# ubuntu 18.04 DNS issue

Tags: dns, systemd-resolved, resolvconf

I have an ubuntu 18.04 server running apache/mysql that can't seem to resolve DNS anymore.

I didn't do anything, but maybe I missed something when checking the server after the last update.

**Here's the issue:**

Everything runs fine, but I can't resolve DNS (on my website as well as via SSH). For example I can't run `sudo apt-get update` . I get the error `Could not resolve 'archive.ubuntu.com'`

**Here's what I already tried:**

symlink fix for `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
sudo ln -s /var/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
```

didn't work.

I realized that resolvconf wasn't installed, so I installed the .deb package manually (as I can't install via apt because of the DNS issue)

didn't work.

I tried messing with the nameservers in the `/etc/resolv.conf` and `/var/run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf`, putting `nameserver 8.8.8.8`

didn't work.

when I ping 8.8.8.8 I don't get anything back (I can talk to `8.8.8.8`, but get 100% packet loss). But this issue might also be a firewall issue. The server is behind a strict firewall to which I don't have access to. But HTTP, HTTPS, NTP, SMTP, DNS are all allowed.

//edit5: ping is blocked by the firewall. so no surprises there.

Currently, my resolv.conf looks like this:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.53
nameserver 8.8.8.8
```

any suggestions would be very much appreciated! thanks!!

here's the output of `systemd-resolve --status`

```
Global
          DNSSEC NTA: 10.in-addr.arpa
                      16.172.in-addr.arpa
                      168.192.in-addr.arpa
                      17.172.in-addr.arpa
                      18.172.in-addr.arpa
                      19.172.in-addr.arpa
                      20.172.in-addr.arpa
                      21.172.in-addr.arpa
                      22.172.in-addr.arpa
                      23.172.in-addr.arpa
                      24.172.in-addr.arpa
                      25.172.in-addr.arpa
                      26.172.in-addr.arpa
                      27.172.in-addr.arpa
                      28.172.in-addr.arpa
                      29.172.in-addr.arpa
                      30.172.in-addr.arpa
                      31.172.in-addr.arpa
                      corp
                      d.f.ip6.arpa
                      home
                      internal
                      intranet
                      lan
                      local
                      private
                      test

Link 2 (ens192)
      Current Scopes: DNS
       LLMNR setting: yes
MulticastDNS setting: no
      DNSSEC setting: no
    DNSSEC supported: no
         DNS Servers: 8.8.8.8
```

//edit:

```
nslookup archive.ubuntu.com 8.8.8.8
```

throws

```
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml contents:

```
network:
    ethernets:
        ens192:
            addresses:
            - 192.168.10.16/24
            gateway4: 192.168.10.1
            nameservers:
                addresses:
                - 8.8.8.8
    version: 2
```

//edit2:

then:

```
nc -v -C 8.8.8.8 53
```

gives me a timeout:

```
nc: connect to 8.8.8.8 port 53 (tcp) failed: Connection timed out
```

also

```
nc -v -C 192.168.10.1 53
nc -v -C 8.8.8.8 853
```

have timeouts

//edit3

```
netstat -nr
```

shows

```
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.10.1    0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 ens192
192.168.10.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 ens192
```

//edit4

is it weird that `netstat -a` shows `127.0.0.53:domain` ?

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:netbios-ssn     0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:domain       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:ssh             0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 localhost.localdoma:ipp 0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

Comment: Post the output of `nslookup archive.ubuntu.com 8.8.8.8`.  Also post the content of the file in `/etc/netplan/`

Comment: ok, i just edited the original post with the outputs of the command as well as the content of 50-cloud-init.yaml. thanks in advance!

Comment: How about these: `nc -v -C 8.8.8.8 53` and `nc -v -C 192.168.10.1 53`

Comment: This one too: `nc -v -C 8.8.8.8 853`

Comment: so weird. they all have timeouts. even nc -v -C 192.168.10.1 53

Comment: Is your system behind a firewall or router?  Are you 100% certain your system has a network connection that is permitted to reach out to other environments?  Are you sure your network connection on your system is actually, in fact, "up" and connected?

Comment: My system is a virtual machine on a physical server in the building of my client (i'm a web developer and designer). it is behind a firewall to which I don't have access to. I've talked to the guy who administrates the firewall and he sent me a screenshot of the open connections on the firewall. but I can't be 100% sure that it's up and connected. the other virtual machines on this server seem to run OK (no errors reported by the company). but I might have access on one other virtual machine and i'll check there if the same problem occurs and will get back to you.

Comment: on the other virtual server which has on the same firewall rules but runs windows, I can access the internet normally. 

also what I just noticed on my ubuntu vserver is: I cannot ping outside the network. Servers in the same network I can reach, but if I try pinging a server in the internet by ip it doesn't work. (ping sent, but 100% packet loss)

Comment: i've just added the output of netstat -nr to the post

Comment: also i've added the beginning of netstat -a

Comment: i've just found out that ping is definitely blocked by the firewall. so I might be able to receive from 8.8.8.8. but can't resolve DNS

Comment: What software are you using to virtualize?  There are network configurations there as well, that is likely where the issues lies.

Comment: they are using VMWare v6

Answer (score 0):

So the admin of the VMWare Server / firewall fixed it. He didn't tell me yet where the problem was. I'm still waiting for his answer. But it wasn't with my system.

Thank you so much for your questions and for trying to help me! The problem actually made me learn quite a bit about network configurations on Linux.

//edit: He finally wrote back and told me that the problem was in the firewall configuration

Cheers